# When I load the page the alert("hey") function appears, why does the js function execute despite no onClick call? How do I prevent it from doing so?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I load the html page the alert("hey") function appears immediately, why does the js function execute despite no onClick call? How do I prevent it from doing so? I'm new to js. Thanks for any help.

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="js/es6.js"></script>

    <script>
        function toggleNav(){
            alert("hey");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: um, should not be alerting.. Are you cached with an old version of the page

Comment: What's in es6.js? Something must be calling it in there, because functions don't call themselves without IIFE syntax.

Comment: Maybe es6.js has an onLoad method

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: In es6.js file the function is called in a link <a href="#" className="hidden" id="i-nav" onClick={toggleNav()}>Menu</a>. The es6.js file is made up react components

Comment: This is the es6 file https://github.com/uppercasenumber/react_01/blob/master/assets/js/es6.js

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you get such alert dialog,here i have ran for two times but without such problem,so check your code and clean your browser cache.or you can also change a browser and test it.
and if the question is still there, i think there maybe a closure function in your extra import js file.what i thought were only that, wish i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The alert Hey is not coming from the toggleNav() function, you should check your head part of HTML to see if there is a javascript file included which could be causing this, or show us what's in your es6.js file, the js function won't be executed unless it is being called like
toggleNav(); in your case.
And even if it was called on the onclick event it wouldn't be executed on the page load. Make sure you reload your page after you saved your changes.

Comment: Thanks Natalie. In es6.js file the function is called in a link <a href="#" className="hidden" id="i-nav" onClick={toggleNav()}>Menu</a>. The es6.js file is made up react components

Comment: This is the es6 file https://github.com/uppercasenumber/react_01/blob/master/assets/js/es6.js